Applying a dynamic number of forces to particles in threejs compute shader
I've been making a particle system using threejs, based off one of the examples, and I've been trying to expand on it by adding functionality for a varying number of attractor objects, just simple pull forces on particles. For one of them its working fine, but as soon as I try to iterate over them it suddenly breaks, only applying the force from the first attractor. However, whenever I add a new attractor item it does a little burst of pulling different particles to the same location.
I have a few instanced storage buffers in which i'm storing particle positions, velocities, and also three buffers for attractor position, strength, and radius. Here's my current compute shader for updating particle positions:
const computeUpdate = Fn(() => {
        // retrieve position and velocity from storage
        const position = positionBuffer.element(instanceIndex);
        const velocity = velocityBuffer.element(instanceIndex);


        let i = 0;
        for (i; i < maxAttractors; i++) {
            const attractorPositionB = attractorPositionBuffer.element(i);
            const attractorRadiusB = attractorRadiusBuffer.element(i);
            const attractorStrengthB = attractorStrengthBuffer.element(i);

            const toAttractor = attractorPositionB.sub(position);
            const distance = toAttractor.length();

            let magnitude = float(999999).pow(attractorRadiusB.sub(distance))
            magnitude = magnitude.clamp(0, 1);

            const direction = toAttractor.div(distance);
            const force = direction.mul(attractorStrengthB.div(distance.pow(2).clamp(50, 999999)).mul(magnitude))
            velocity.addAssign(force);
        }

        // apply forces
        //velocity.addAssign(totalForce);
        velocity.addAssign(gravity);
        //velocity.mulAssign(damping);

        position.addAssign(velocity);

    });

I know that my attractors are being initialized correctly, and if I take the code out of the for loop and manually specify and index it works perfectly, but in the loop it only does the first attractor, with no errors in the console.
I've also tried unwrapping the loop block, as I thought it might have been an issue with the for loop itself, but when I did so, it had the exact same effect as with the for loop.
